# Pick<S, K> type with dynamic/computed keys

Tags: reactjs, generics, typescript, components

The latest `@types/react` (`v15.0.6`) make use of features added in TypeScript 2.1 for `setState`, namely `Pick<S, K>`. Which is a good thing, because now the typings are correct, because before the update typings "didn't know" that `setState` is merging `this.state`, rather than replacing it.

Also, using `Pick` makes the `setState` function very strict in terms of allowed input. It is no longer possible to add properties to the `state` that aren't defined in the component definition (second generic of `React.Component`.

But it is also harder to define a dynamic update handler. For example:

```
import * as React from 'react';


interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number|undefined;
}


export default class PersonComponent extends React.Component<void, Person> {
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      name: '',
      age: undefined
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate (e:React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const key = e.currentTarget.name as keyof Person;
    const value = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({ [key]: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleUpdate} />
        <input type="text" name="age" value={this.state.age} onChange={this.handleUpdate} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The `setState` function will throw the following error

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable 
     to parameter of type 'Pick<Person, "name" | "age">'.
       Property 'name' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; }'.
```

even though the type of `key` is `"name" | "age"`.

I can not find a solution for this, other than having a separate `updateName` and `updateAge` function. Does anyone know how to use `Pick` with dynamic key values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So after doing more research I can provide a little more context on what is happening in the above code.

When you do something like `const name = 'Bob'` the type of the variable `name` is `'Bob'` *not* string. However, if you replace the `const` with a `let` (`let name = 'Bob'`) the variable `name` will be of type `string`.

This concept is called "widening". Basically, it means that the type system tries to be as explicit as possible. Because `const` can not be reassigned TypeScript can infer the exact type. `let` statements can be reassigned. Thus, TypeScript will infer `string` (in the above example) as the type of `name`.

The same is happening with `const key = e.currentTarget.name as keyof Person`. `key` will be of (union) type `"name"|"age"`, which is exactly what we want it to be. *But* in the expression `this.setState({ [key]: value });` variable `key` is (incorrectly) widened to a `string`.

---

**tl;dr;** It seems like there is a bug in TypeScript. I posted the issue to the Github repo and the TypeScript team [is investigating the problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948#issuecomment-278571208). :)

As a temporary workaround you can do:

```
this.setState({ [key as any]: value });
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Has this been fixed or any other workaround for this case ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Sebastian no longer works for me (though at one stage it did). I now do the following until it is resolved in Typescript core (as per the issue listed in Sebastians answer):

```
  handleUpdate (e:React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const newState = {};
    newState[e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(newState);
  }
```

It's lame, but it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem.

```
type State = {
  name: string,
  age: number | undefined
};

type StateKeys = keyof State;

dynSetState(key: StateKeys, value: string) {
  this.setState({
    [key]: value
  } as Pick<State, keyof State>)
}
```

This will still give an error appropriately if the value is not in the set of possible property value types, but will not give you an error if the keys are not within the set of possible property keys.

Ref : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635