# Assignment of generic object to Partial type

Tags: typescript

After a while I'm working again on TypeScript, but I'm stuck at this issue.

```
export class CrossBrowserStorage<T> {
  getValue<P extends keyof T>(
    key: P,
    defaultValue: T[P]
  ): Observable<T[P]> {
    return this.getValues({ [key]: defaultValue }).pipe(map(values => values[key]));
                      ----^ TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: T[P]; }' is not assignable 
                            to parameter of type 'Partial '
  }

  getValues(keys: Partial<T>): Observable<Partial<T>> {
    return from(browser.storage.sync.get(keys) as Promise<Partial<T>>);
  }
}
```

> TS2345: Argument of type `'{ [x: string]: T[P]; }'` is not assignable to
>   parameter of type `'Partial'`

Can't understand how to solve this while maintaining correct typings.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a mixture of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788853/typescript-assigning-pickt-k-to-partialt) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090191/picks-k-type-with-dynamic-computed-keys): the computed key gets widened to `string`; and even if you narrow it to `P`, the compiler still can't verify in the generic case.  You'll need to use a type assertion like `{ [key]: defaultValue } as Pick<T, P> as Partial<T>`.  If those other answers don't cover your issue let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the compiler won't be able to verify this for you, and in cases like this where you know more the compiler, a reasonable solution is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
class Class<T> {
    f<K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: T[K]) {
        const badPartial: Partial<T> = { [k]: v }; // error!
        const goodPartial: Partial<T> = { [k]: v } as Pick<T, K> & Partial<T>; // okay
    }
}
```

So that's what you need to do.  But why is it like this?  There seem to be two main stumbling blocks that the compiler is facing.

---

The first stumbling block is that the compiler only knows how to interpret computed properties if the key is a single statically known literal or unique symbol type:

```
const k1 = "a";
const o1 = { [k1]: 123 }; 
// const o1: {[k1]: number};
o1.a; // okay
o1.b; // error
```

If, instead, if the key type is generic or a union of string literals, the compiler widens it to `string` and treats the resulting object as one with a [string index signature](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), to strange results:

```
const k2 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "z";
const o2 = { [k2]: 123 };
// const o2: {[x: string]:number};
o2.a; // no error, but might not exist
o2.b; // no error, but *definitely* doesn't exist

function foo<K extends string>(k3: K) {
    const o3 = { [k3]: 123 };
    // const o3: {[x: string]:number};
    o3.a; // no error, but probably doesn't exist
}
```

This is an open issue in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  It's sort of clear what the "right thing" to do would be for the case of unions of literals; presumably `o2` above should be of type `{a: number} | {z: number}`.  It's less clear with generics; perhaps `o3` above should be of type `Partial<Record<K, number>>`.  In any case, a string index signature isn't great and breaks things like you've seen.

---

Another stumbling block is that even if the compiler realized that the computed property was assignable to some suitable type depending on generic types `T` and `K`, it probably wouldn't be able to recognize that this type is assignable to `Partial<T>`.  It's easy enough for a human being to see this, but the compiler can't necessarily reason about higher order type manipulation of this sort.  The canonical open issue about this is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884), where the issue is that `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` is not seen as compatible with `T`, when `T` or `K` is generic.  For any statically known type `T` and `K`, the compiler could do the analysis: `Pick<{a: string, b: string}, "a"> & Omit<{a: string, b: string}, "a">` is indeed seen as assignable to `{a: string, b: string}`.  But once you make the types generic, the compiler essentially gives up.

---

For both of those reasons, there's little chance of getting the compiler to verify the assignability for you.  And the best advice I can give is to use that type assertion and move on.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QDwBUB80DeAoavoDNEBpaAUwA8AXUgOwBMYBrUgTwHt9o0AKRgLmhEANNABuA5AG0iAXQCUmHHmXA2NCJWgAjMHQAKYAE6UAlmBACDxsyBToAvJmiTGMgaOgBfANzQA9H5khoZshgCESsq4quqaAOZsbPpGpuaWKTZ20I4Yzq7uXtCQ0HomwIwoIkToAGQlGeZ2vgHQbIxgLJFeWJ5YWDEa0IwAjNnQAERg4979aoNsozl5w27QwwBMAMxeMy0DmgsCGC4rAjQArgC2WqSGPlgLAHRgzYFtHQ-Dj1qvQSGGfX2Q3WYwAsmBKAALR6GMD0NiXbgKRDQAAMjwArNAAPwTKbQATjABe01msVaIKWLnWqw223uezmB3WR0k5AEGkMJhocTcF2ut3ubHWz1+NDYf1CIi0500lxMcUhmnFmgoJg0DxFP38gXFksM0tl0AAVHRSPhuSZqCAWMboHQ2KQIDQAOSq8jqyh9fDnGjAUxqAiJYhkKi0BjQTncuKoXibAREBTYFRM1rbKmMTa0rY7LqM8lseOYNkcyhcnl8q43O4zZSF0U66B627-Q2aAAOIR0Wht9sdzrdoc9PWgQA)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a super complete answer. I don't particularly like adding code when it shouldn't be needed, but hey, nevermind this time.